# WolframAlpha Geometric Probability Distribution Function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

While using my WolframAlpha mobile app for calculations, I noticed they the geometric pdf  they list seems inconsistent with my understanding (screen shot attached). I believe it should be $p (1-p)^{x-1}$. 
Is WolframAlpha wrong, or more likely, am I wrong?[image: geometric pdf]

Comment: See the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) article on the geometric distribution. There are two conventions, yours is one and WA's is the other.

Comment: @MikeEarnest ahh ok; I see it refers to k failures in this convention. I didn’t realize but I appreciate it; got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be closed:

The question has been answered in the comments; there are two different conventions for the geometric distribution, as explained in [the corresponding Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).